# nnet function in R

Tags: r, neural-networks

I have 7 input variables,2 hidden neuron and 1 output variable.the train sample are 50. I used `nnet()` function in **R** to train my network but it returns 187-2-50 network with 526 weights means 187 inputs and 50 outputs. Does it work right? if not, how can I get the right number of inputs and outputs?

```
net <- nnet(mande ~ bed + bes + ATM + salery.day.effect +
            off.day.effect + week.dat + work.day,
            data = train.data, size = 2, decay = 5e-4, maxit = 200)
```

Answer (score 1):

ouputs: Are you sure your mande variable is not a 50 level factor or something like that? In case you want a regression you have to have a numeric output, not a factor.

inputs: I supose that at least one of the seven variables are factors so each one of them generates in the model k-1 inputs, decoded as 1-0 variables, being k the number of levels of the factor.